# Learning Haskell: Making a function that returns a list of elements that only appear once

Tags: haskell, recursion, list-comprehension

I'm learning Haskell and I'm trying to make a recursive function that receives a List of integers and returns a List of integers that only appears once in the list ( `once :: [Int] -> [Int]` ), so, for example, if the input list is `[4, 8, 1, 5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 2]` the return would be `[8, 5, 6, 3]` , but I'm having some problems making the code, in how to make this into a recursive function.

I'm also trying to make it using list comprehension, I'm currently reading about it on Learn You A Haskell, but um also stuck, so if you also have an idea on how to make it using list comprehension I would be thankful to see how both implementations work.

Edit:

```
once [] = []
once (x:xs)
             | (x `notElem` xs) = x : once xs
             | otherwise = once xs
```

But as it is my code is doing the exact opposite, is returning me the repeated elements, and when I try to invert the return of the guards it just returns the complete list without the repeated elements, I'm really out of ideas on how to make it return what I want, only the unique elements that apear once in the list.

Comment: What did you try, what is not working?

Comment: Recursively I'm trying to do something like ` once [] = 0 ` ` once (x:xs) | (x elem xs) = `, I know I have to use `elem` to find if the element im seen is already on the list, and if its not then some how add it to a list I'll return at the end, but idk how to do that, how to, when `elem` tells me the element is unique, to add it to a list.

Comment: The problem is that once you get to the *last* occurrence of a repeated element, it is no longer in the remainder of the list. You need to use `filter` as recommended by Willem Van Onsem to clear the repeated elements so that they won't be reconsidered later.

Answer (score 3):

There are basically three possible cases:

1. the list is empty, so then we return an empty list;
2. the list is not empty, and the first item `x` is an element in the remaining list `xs`, then we skip that item and filter out all items in the tail when we recurse; and
3. the list is not empty and the first item `x` does not appear in the rest of the list `xs`, in that case we yield `x`, and recurse on `xs`.

The function thus looks like:

```
once :: [Int] -> [Int]
once [] = []
once (x:xs)
  | x `elem` xs = …
  | otherwise = …
```

I leave it as an exercise to fill in the `…` parts. For the second case, you can make use of [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter).

Comment: I got that far, I edited my question to the problem im currently facing